# Custom css font display with interference after publishing site to Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, font-face

Trying to post web-site at different hostings (somee.com, azure, localhost). Site at asp.net mvc 4.

Displaying at the localhost and somee.com:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58930284/testing/font_local.png

At the Azure Web site:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58930284/testing/font_azure.png

css:

```
@font-face 
{
   font-family: 'Font name';
   src: url("fonts/Font name.eot");
   src: url("fonts/Font name.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
     url("fonts/Font name.woff") format("woff"),
     url("fonts/Font name.ttf") format("truetype"),
     url("fonts/Font name.svg") format("svg");
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> IIS 7 will not return file types that are not added to the
>    element or that have mappings in the 
>   element by default. This behavior prevents unauthorized access to
>   files that do not have mappings in the IIS 7 configuration settings.

Basically, IIS does not return static files that it does not know about its media type. Therefore, you need to add unknown mime types manually.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
       <staticContent>
         <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
         <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
         <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"  />
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
       </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Place this configuration to webconfig file in your project.